# Is there any charge to monitor a azure resource using API through Zabbix?

Tags: azure, zabbix

Is there any charge in azure for each API call?

I'm going to use [Zabbix template for azure](https://www.zabbix.com/br/integrations/azure), which use Azure API

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just hitting the Azure Monitor APIs, which it looks like it is, then there is no cost for this.

If you started storing log data in log analytics, or created custom metrics then this would add a cost.

Answer (score 0):

For metrics the First 1,000,000 API calls per month are free.